# How to read excel file to deedle Frame?

Tags: c#, deedle

Is it possible to read data from xls file to deedle Frame directly? I found that Deedle.Excel has openExcel method, but couldn't use it. If it's possible please provide example.

Comment: What connection string did you use for the Deedle.Excel?  Did you use a JET or ACE driver?  Is your excel file xls (Excel 2003) or xlsx (Excel 2007+)?

Comment: xls. Do I need any driver? Can Deedle.Excel read it without any driver?

Comment: Yes you need a driver.  I would have to do research to fined the connection string Deedle uses.  I suspect Deedle is use JET and you have a xlsx file which needs ACE.  Jet is a windows driver.  ACE is part of Microsoft Office so Deedle may be using ACE but Microsoft Office is not installed.  So then you would need to install ACE without Office.  I've never been successful in doing this but other have reported it is possible to install ACE without a Microsoft Office License.

Comment: The dependencies on follow page says Excel is required.  Which either means you Need ACE or Deedle is using Excel Interop (then the Excel Interop needs to be installed).

Comment: the csproj has following : <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> (which either has ACE or the Interop).  And release notes says following : This package installs the core Deedle package, NetOffice.Excel, and a Deedle extension
  which makes it possible to send Deedle Frames to Excel."""

Comment: It appears from the core documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0) that it sues the Interop.  The above link has a paragraph "Windows Native Interop" and the paragraph has a link to an example that uses Interop.  So you probably have to go to msdn and download the Interop for the version of Office Installed on machine.

Comment: Here is the reference to the Excel SDK : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/programming-with-the-c-api-in-excel.  Make sure the SDK was downloaded.  The runtime versions usually do not need a license and are meant for stand-alone installations : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I created a library that reads xlsb, xlsx, xls, csv and txt and transforms to a Deedle frame. It also puts a Deedle frame back to an Excel spreadsheet. It uses EPPlus for the xlsx part, so no driver is required.

Here is a script version of the XLS-Load part of the code (I omitted the other features for brevity):

```
#r @"C:\Users\flavi\.nuget\packages\deedle\2.1.2\lib\net45\Deedle.dll"
#r @"C:\Users\flavi\.nuget\packages\epplus\5.0.4\lib\net45\EPPlus.dll"

open Deedle

module private Functions =
    let adjustStartCell (startRow,startCol) = max startRow 1,max startCol 1        //prevents errors if input is smaller than 1

module private XLSX = 
    open OfficeOpenXml
    open System.IO
    open Functions

    let load (fi : FileInfo) (sheetName:string) startLine startCol hasHeaders takeUntil skipCols =
        using (new ExcelPackage(fi)) (fun p ->            
            let wsOpt = p.Workbook.Worksheets.[sheetName] |> Option.ofObj
            match wsOpt with
            |Some ws ->           
                let adjStartLine,adjStartCol = adjustStartCell (startLine,startCol)      //prevents errors if input is smaller than 1
                let linePlusHeaders = adjStartLine + if hasHeaders then 1 else 0    //skips 1 line in case there's a header
                let lastRow = ws.Dimension.End.Row              //gets last row of the given sheet to know when to stop getting data
                let filteredSkipCols = skipCols |> List.filter (fun x -> x<>"")
                Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> (i+adjStartCol,string ws.Cells.[adjStartLine,adjStartCol+i].Value))  //inits col dimension mapping
                |> Seq.takeWhile (fun (_,elem) ->
                                match elem with
                                |null|"" -> false                   //stops taking data when founds the first empty cell
                                |txt when txt = takeUntil -> false  //or when a specific value is provided
                                |_ -> true)
                |> (fun h -> if hasHeaders then h else h |> Seq.mapi (fun i (c,_) -> (c,string (i+1))))
                |> Seq.map (fun (col,header) ->
                Seq.initInfinite (fun i ->      //starts getting row data
                i,header,ws.Cells.[i+linePlusHeaders,col].Value)
                |> Seq.takeWhile (fun (row,_,_) -> row<=lastRow-linePlusHeaders)
                |> (fun s -> if filteredSkipCols<>[] then s |> Seq.filter (fun (_,hd,_) -> filteredSkipCols |> List.contains hd |> not) else s)) //filter columns
                |> Seq.concat |> Frame.ofValues |> Ok                    
            |None -> Result.Error("Worksheet not found: " + sheetName + "."))

module private Controller =
    open System.IO

    let load filePath sheetName startLine startCol hasHeaders takeUntil skipCols =
        try 
            let file = new FileInfo(filePath)
            match file.Exists,file.Extension.ToLower() with
            | false,_ -> Result.Error ("The file does not exist: " + filePath)
            | _,".xlsx" | _,".xls" -> XLSX.load file sheetName startLine startCol hasHeaders takeUntil skipCols
            | _ -> Result.Error("Invalid file extension: " + file.Extension)
        with 
            |ex -> Result.Error(ex.Message)

[<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
type API private() =
    static let getDefaultParams startcell hasHeaders takeUntil skipCols sheetName =
        let (startLine,startCol) = defaultArg startcell (1,1)
        let hasHeaders0 = defaultArg hasHeaders true
        let takeUntil0 = defaultArg takeUntil ""
        let skipCols0 = defaultArg skipCols []
        let sheetName0 = defaultArg sheetName "Sheet1"
        ((startLine,startCol),hasHeaders0,takeUntil0,skipCols0,sheetName0)

    static member safeLoad(filePath, ?sheetName, ?startcell, ?hasHeaders, ?takeUntil, ?skipCols) =
        let (startLine,startCol),hasHeaders0,takeUntil0,skipCols0,sheetName0 = getDefaultParams startcell hasHeaders takeUntil skipCols sheetName
        Controller.load filePath sheetName0 startLine startCol hasHeaders0 takeUntil0 skipCols0

    static member unsafeLoad(filePath, ?sheetName, ?startcell, ?hasHeaders, ?takeUntil, ?skipCols) =
        let (startLine,startCol),hasHeaders0,takeUntil0,skipCols0,sheetName0 = getDefaultParams startcell hasHeaders takeUntil skipCols sheetName
        match Controller.load filePath sheetName0 startLine startCol hasHeaders0 takeUntil0 skipCols0 with
        |Ok df -> df
        |Result.Error e -> failwith(e)

//example of how to use:
API.unsafeLoad(@"C:\someFolder\someFile.xlsx","SomeSheet")
```

Answer (score 0):

after install deedle.excel and ExcelDataReader.DataSet, I use the following code(I'm not sure if this is the best ,but at least it works):

```
using Deedle;
using ExcelDataReader;

// your code is omit
...
// below is the key code
            Frame<int, string> mydf;

            using (var stream = File.Open(myFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                    {
                        UseColumnDataType = true,
                        ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true,  // to use the first row as header
                        }
                    });
                    DataTableReader rd = result.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();  //just use the first sheet
                    mydf = Frame.ReadReader(rd);
                }
            }

// use mydf below
...
```